# Searching a string in Excel (multiple worksheets) with VB6

Tags: excel, search, vb6

I' new to VB6 and I want to search a specific string in an excel file with multiple worksheets. I' m trying to do it with the classic linear search in do .. while loop. The goal of my code is to find a specific string that is taken from a txt field and print the previous and next cell. I would like to ask you if there is any simple method for that function and where can I find good documentations with examples.

Answer (score 0):

It's a long time ago, i did such things.
What helped me, was creating a Macro in Excel, doing exact the things you want the program to do
Copy and change the VB Code from the Macro Script.
Have Fun, John